# pygame install returns error no version and no satisfying distribution

Tags: python, pip, pygame

I have been trying to install pygame using pip with the command

```
py -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

but this returns the error message: "  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygame"

I have tried installing another library with pip and everything worked perfectly.

This is the full code response:

```
PS C:\Users\Uzay> py -m pip install -U pygame --user
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pygame
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pygame/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pygame/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pygame/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pygame/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pygame/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pygame/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygame
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Any answer is appreciated. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this on terminal: pip install pygame